# How can I get components in repository via nexus3 api?

Tags: nexus, nexus3

I have a raw repository in nexus3, named "marvel".
In the repository I have about 5000 components with the name "spiderman" in them (e.g. "spiderman-22", "directory/spiderman-tar", etc).

I want to get a list of the components in the repository.

I saw in [their website](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/components-api) a way to get components via api:

```
curl -u admin:admin123 -X GET 'http://localhost:8081/service/rest/v1/components?repository=marvel'
```

I have two issues:

1. I don't get all the components from the api (they probably have a limits - and I need about 5000 components).
2. How do I add search for the api (i.e. only components with the name "spiderman")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. I don't get all the components from the api (they probably have a limits - and I need about 5000 components).

Every needed API endpoint is paginated. As explained in [the documentation](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/pagination), you have to call the same uri with a continuation token e.g.:

```
GET /service/rest/v1/<api>?<query>&continuationToken=88491cd1d185dd136f143f20c4e7d50c
```

> 2. How do I add search for the api (i.e. only components with the name "spiderman")?

By using the dedicated [`search` API endpoint](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/search-api)

Note that you can have a view over the API and try it out from your browser by calling the swagger page on your own nexus installation: http(s)://your.nexus.server/swagger-ui/

You can also navigate to it from Server Admin > System > API.